# SSL certificate for multiple dock containers running on RPI 4

Tags: pi-4, connection, security, services, docker

Hi guys I have a question regarding docker containers and ssl certificates.
I want to install more than one docker containers like pi hole , Bitwarden and motioneye .
To access them I have to type their IP address and port number on the browser but the connection is insecure.
If I generate my own ssl certificate will it be applied to all the services running through this IP address or the port which are running makes it so that I will need a different SSL for every service ?
I am running everything in an RPI 4. I would like to use LetsEncrypt but I can’t do that locally .

Thank you in advance for your answers !

Comment: What I mean in case I confused you is, the self signed ssl Will be assigned to the IP address , in this case to my RPI , and all services running on this RPI will be secure or should I make an ssl for each individual service ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm learning to do something similar myself. I think the step you are missing here is that you can use a reverse proxy, such as NGINX Proxy Manager, so that you don't need to "type their IP address and port number on the browser", as you mentioned, but instead can access each application as a subdomain, with the proxy directing inbound traffic automatically to the necessary port(s). Then you can generate your SSL certificates based on the subdomain URL. That is just my understanding so far of how it works. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question: Yes, you can use the same certificate for multiple services running on different ports on the same server.

But is a pain in the a.. if the certificate expires and you have to replace it for every single service. Therefore I would opt for a reverse proxy doing the SSL-stuff at one place as Fritt Ro mentiond. I use Traefik as loadbalancer for multiple backend http-containers and even for other protocols (e.g. mqtt).